# Use a local XSD for an XML document

Tags: android, xml, xsd

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<linii xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="file:///C:/Users/Cosmin/Desktop/MyApplication/app/src/main/res/values/linii.xsd">
    <linia id="1">
        <indicativ>19</indicativ>
        <nume>Auchan</nume>
        <traseu>1</traseu>
    </linia>

    <linia id="2">
        <indicativ>20</indicativ>
        <nume>Carrefour ERA</nume>
        <traseu>2</traseu>
    </linia>
</linii>
```

And my XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="linii">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="linia" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="indicativ"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:string" name="nume"/>
                            <xs:element type="xs:byte" name="traseu"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute type="xs:byte" name="id" use="optional"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I get the following error:

> Element linii must be declared

Why? I'm working in Android Studio.
[CoreFiling](http://www.corefiling.com/opensource/schemaValidate.html) validate both, XML and XSD.

Comment: I think that you should use `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:/Users/Cosmin/Desktop/MyApplication/app/src/main/res/values/linii.xsd"`

Comment: It's even worse, the path is not recognized in that way.

Comment: As suggested at [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757863(v=vs.85).aspx) .. after `file:` put only two `/` not three.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML document and your XSD are fine, and your XML document is valid against your XSD.

The format of the file specified by `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` is also correct.  (Yes, it should have three `/` separators as you have -- `file://` plus an (empty) machine specifier plus another `/` followed by the directory path to the file.  Most XML processors (including those based on the widely used XML parser, Xerces) expect this format; oddballs ([MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757863(v=vs.85).aspx)) are unfortunately possible, though.)

So why is the processor not finding your XSD if all those things are correct?

Probably there's a hard-to-spot error somewhere along the file path.

**Here's how to find an error (or errors) along a file path:**

1. Enter the full local URI (`file:///C:/Users/Cosmin/Desktop/MyApplication/app/src/main/res/values/linii.xsd`) into Chrome or Firefox.  If the XSD
   comes up, you know your specification to the XSD is correct, and you
   might suspect that your XML processor has an [idiosyncratic expectation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms757863(v=vs.85).aspx).
2. If the XSD is not found, lop off the XSD, and see if a directory
   listing is shown.  If a directory listing is shown, then you've
   spelled the XSD wrong; fix it.  If a directory listing is not shown,
   there's still an error somewhere higher up the path.  Continue
   lopping off parent directories and checking whether you see the
   directory until you find the place in the path where the reality of
   your file system deviates from what's specified in the XSD's path.